# How to do this: a=a+1 in sql server query?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, syntax

how I can do this: a=a+1 in sql server query?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are going to need to provide a little more information

Answer (score 8):

If you want to increase the value of a column in a specific row, this will do it for you:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnname = columnname + 1
WHERE primarykey = id
```

Other than that, please specify what you mean by your question.

Answer (score 7):

You really need to provide more information... folk have given answers for updating a column; so for completeness here's how to declare, init and increment a variable:

```
DECLARE @a INT

SET @a = 10
SET @a = @a + 1
```

Comment: Nice, I was about to answer the same.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE mytable SET a = a + 1 WHERE row_condition

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName = ColumnName + 1 WHERE WhateverYouWant = WhatEverYouNeed
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also legal to update variables in SQL 2005 using the following

```
declare @a int

select column1, column2, @a = @a + column3
from table
where condition
```

It's similar to Ahmet KAKICI's answer just using a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2008 introduced new T-SQL syntax for "[Compound Assignment Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721270.aspx)"

```
DECLARE @price AS MONEY = 10.00;
SET @price += 2.00;
SELECT @price;
```